# Magento Error 405 When Logging In Backend

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a aggravating problem with my magento. When I go to login first thing every morning and go to my domain.com/admin panel and click login after entering my credentials. When I hit the login button it just loads and loads and loads until it shows error 405 Not Allowed. When I inspect the page it shows

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Not Allowed) for https://MY DOMAIN.com/index.php/admin

I do eventually get in after logging in over and over and over again. I have tried using IE, Firefox, and Chrome with no success.

Can someone please help me out here. Im lost for words. Its acting like a permission issue however it does eventually work. So I just dont know.

Magento 1.9 is my version

Comment: can you send me email id?

Answer (score 0):

#### 405 Status Code Explained

The method you are using to access the file is not allowed.A request was made of a resource using a request method not supported by that resource;for example, using GET on a form which requires data to be presented via POST, or using PUT on a read-only resource.

#### Why it Comes

HTTP 405 errors relate to particular objects on a web site, whereas HTTP 501 errors occur when a method is not allowed throughout a site. The method specified in the Request-Line is not allowed for the resource identified by the Request-URI. The response MUST include an Allow header containing a list of valid methods for the requested resource.

#### Fixing 405 Error code

You may be attempting to run a script that is not supported. Some ISPs do not allow scripts on their servers, which could result in this status code. If you are monitor your website through 100pulse, we will intimate whenever you encounter 405 status code error through e-mail or Short message service.

#### Note :

Check log file & see which file contain error.

Comment: Hi. I have this same issue except I can login eventually after attempting to login after 3 times. Then dont have issues the rest of the day. It just mainly happens in the morning time when nobody has been logged in for several hours. So this doesnt seem like a ISP is preventing a script from running does it? As it works after 3 tries. @paarth

Answer (score 0):

When you say

> it loads it loads

Sound like more an issue with hosting, memory limit and some other timeouts (mysql, apache, php, etc) easy debuggable by hosting support.

Also i suggest you those steps

1. Deep clean cache and session
2. Edit `app/etc/local.xml` and set TRUE at `disable all modules`
3. Log back again in admin e put webserver error and access logs in `tail -f /path/to/logs`

Tell us how it goes without loading any module. If this work, you now have a clear picture that a module is not working correctly but finding which is just second part of the story :)